# Is there way to force eject the drive automatically in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to force eject the drive in Cocoa. I found the way as below:

1. I will use the command to eject the drive: `hdiutil eject -force /Volumes/TRAVELDRIVE`
2. Then I will execute this command terminal from Cocoa app by using `NSTask`.

Can I do that by using above steps? If you have best solution, please give me any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened when you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the BSD APIs, i.e.

Open the device `(fd = open("/dev/disk1", O_RDONLY))`

and send the eject `ioctl` to it. Look in `/usr/include/dev/disk.h`.

This may eject the device without unmounting the volume first though, which would leave things in an inconsistent state...

*[Source...](http://forums.macnn.com/79/developer-center/80718/eject-cd-with-cocoa/)

Comment: Can i ask you one more thing? On MAC OS, Can i set permission or do anything to prevent my app by user? I mean I want to deny normal user (not Admin) deleting my app. Can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use I/O Kit or POSIX APIs or NSTask or AppleScript. 
There is no Objective-C API provided.

Comment: Applescript will fail in sandboxed apps. And NSTask ... how that can eject, you say no api available then what to do with this class?